# How do I sort the array from highest to lowest using the swap method?

Tags: c#, sorting

I need to find a away to sort the names and scores from highest to lowest. I'm unsure how to use the swap method and would love it if someone could help show me the way. Also, is there a way to display the scores so they are aligned a little neater?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace proj09LEA
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // declare and array of integers          
            string[] name = new string[5];
            int[] score = new int[5];

            Console.WriteLine("\nSaturday Coder's Bowling Team");
            Console.WriteLine("Enter in a name and score for each person on the team.");
            Console.WriteLine("For example, Mary 143. Just hit Enter when you are done.\n");

            // fill an array with user input
            for (int i = 0; i < score.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter in a name and score: ");
                //save the name and score as a string
                string line = Console.ReadLine();

                //split the name and score
                name[i] = line.Substring(0, line.IndexOf(' '));
                score[i] = int.Parse(line.Substring(line.IndexOf(' ') + 1));
            }

            Console.WriteLine("------------ Input Complete ------------\n");
            Console.WriteLine("Here are the scores for this game, from highest to lowest:\n");

            for (int i = 0; i < score.Length; i++)
            {
                if (score[i] >= 300)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}     {1}*.", name[i], score[i]);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}     {1}", name[i], score[i]);
                }
            }

            //display the average score in the program 
            AverageScore(score);

            Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to continue. . .");
            //end program 
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        // find the average score from the score array
        static void AverageScore(int[] score)
        {
            int sum = score.Sum();
            int average = sum / score.Length;
            Console.WriteLine("\nThe average score for this game was {0:D}.\n", average);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to implement a method that will test score entries against each other, and once you find that something is bigger or smaller swap those elements with another method...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't keep seperate arrays for your names and scores.  Create a class with a Name and Score property.  Implement IComparable in the class and you can use the built-in List.Sort on your class.

```
public class BowlingScore : IComparable<BowlingScore>
{
    private int _score = 0;

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public bool IsPerfectGame { get; protected set; }

    public int Score
    {
        get { return this._score; }

        set { this._score = value; this.IsPerfectGame = value == 300; }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        if (this.IsPerfectGame)
        {
            return string.Format("{0}'s score was *{1}", this.Name, this.Score);
        }
        else
        {
            return string.Format("{0}'s score was {1}", this.Name, this.Score);

        }
    }

    public int CompareTo(BowlingScore other)
    {
        if (other == null) return 1;

        return -1 * this.Score.CompareTo(other.Score);
    }
```

This code will collect names and scores from the Console, sort from high to low and print out the scores and print out the high, low, and average scores:

```
        List<BowlingScore> scores = new List<BowlingScore>(5);

        for (int index = 0; index < 5; index++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter in a name and score: ");
            string line = Console.ReadLine();

            BowlingScore bowlingScore = new BowlingScore();
            bowlingScore.Name = line.Substring(0, line.IndexOf(' '));
            bowlingScore.Score = int.Parse(line.Substring(line.IndexOf(' ') + 1));

            scores.Add(bowlingScore);
        }

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Here are the Scores:");

        scores.Sort();

        foreach (BowlingScore score in scores)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(score);
        }

        Console.WriteLine();
        HighScores(scores);

        Console.WriteLine();
        LowScores(scores);

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Average score:{0}", scores.Average(f => f.Score)));

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key...");
        Console.ReadKey();

    static void LowScores(List<BowlingScore> scores)
    {
        int highScore = scores.ElementAt(scores.Count - 1).Score;

        for (int index = scores.Count - 1; index > 0; index--)
        {
            BowlingScore bowlingScore = scores.ElementAt(index);

            if (bowlingScore.Score == highScore)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Low Score: {0} {1}", bowlingScore.Name, bowlingScore.Score));
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    static void HighScores(List<BowlingScore> scores)
    {
        int lowScore = scores.ElementAt(0).Score;

        for (int index = 0; index < scores.Count; index++)
        {
            BowlingScore bowlingScore = scores.ElementAt(index);

            if (bowlingScore.Score == lowScore)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("High Score: {0} {1}", bowlingScore.Name, bowlingScore.Score));
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```